Can I set a background color with alpha transparency in face-attribute
I would like to have a background color on all my headers which is 80% transparent white - so that it works fine in any theme. Currently I'm using the below config to set the hex code as the background based on the current theme, but I'm not sure how to add transparency to it.
(set-face-attribute org-level-1 nil :foreground "magenta" background #"282a36")

is it possible to set the background color to something like RGBA(120, 50, 212, 0.2)?

:background "FF"?

@crocefisso, I was actually looking for alpha transparency. I have updated the question accordingly. But this is good insight, I wasn't aware tha "FF" results in a transparent color.
